# Rspec falling with ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch "x" expected, got "x" when running all specs; but not when separately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new at the project that has some spec coverage and when i run all of the specs, all the comparation fails with the same 
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch "x" expected, got "x", e.g.:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
>         User(#103950560) expected, got User(#107825100)

There is one spec, that when being excluded makes all work. And itself when run separately works fine.

I can't post here it's content i guess though 8(

cache_classes = true resolves this.

My coworkers on Macs do not have this bug, while me and a couple of people on Ubuntu have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I have updated `factory_girl_rails` to the latest version, bumping up  `factory_girl` from `2.6.4` to `3.2.0` and it fixed it!

Comment: Now factory_girl_rails changed its name to factory_bot_rails, and upgrading my facotry_bot_rails did not help.